# Как получить ref активной NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

В навигации есть указатель, который должен позиционироваться относительно активной ссылки. Как правильно получить реф этой ссылки для расчета позиции указателя ?

```js
const Aside = ({ newMessages }) => {

  return (
    <aside className="aside">
      <nav className="nav">
        <div className="nav__content">
          <ul>
            <li className="nav__link">
              <NavLink to="/" exact className="nav__link">
                <div className="icon">
                  <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
                </div>
                <span className="nav__link-name">Профиль</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav__link">
              <NavLink to="/chat" className="nav__link">
                <div className="icon">
                  {newMessages ? (
                    <Indicator className="nav__link-indicator" value={newMessages} />
                  ) : null}
                  <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <span className="nav__link-name">Сообщения</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav__link">
              <NavLink to="/social" className="nav__link">
                <div className="icon">
                  <i className="fas fa-users"></i>
                </div>
                <span className="nav__link-name">Люди</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="nav__dot"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  );
};
```

Comment: Не ясно в чем Ваш вопрос. Разверните подробнее

Comment: Задача в том, что нужно динамически получать реф активной ссылки NavLink. Этот реф будет передаваться в функцию, которая определяет ее координаты на странице и позиционирует указатель (.nav__dot). Я не смог найти api для получения DOM элемента активной ссылки NavLink

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы можете получать хуком useLocation текущий route, а в самих NavLink присваивать какойто className, если его href совпадает со значение в useLocation. А в css вы уже указываете указателя. Но мне кажется я не правильно понял вопроса